# Using JQuery to capture change in a Telerik MVC ComboBoxFor

Tags: jquery, combobox, telerik-mvc

I am using the following code to capture change text in HTML inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input', document.myForm).bind("change", function() { setConfirmUnload(true); }); 
});
```

this works fine for normal textboxes and checkboxes.

I'm using Telerik's MVC ComboBoxFor which renders input tags, but does not seem to trigger the above JQuery.

Any ideas how to capture this?

This is how the HTML renders:

```
<div class="t-widget t-combobox t-header" id="InterviewRequired">
<div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default">
    <input class="t-input" id="InterviewRequired-input" name="InterviewRequired-input" title="InterviewRequired" type="text" value="Select" />
    <span class="t-select t-header">
        <span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">select</span>
    </span>
</div>
<input id="InterviewRequired-value" name="InterviewRequired" style="display:none" type="text" value="0" />
```

I've also asked this question on the [Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/combobox/using-jquery-to-capture-change-in-a-telerik-mvc-comboboxfor.aspx) in case I don't get an answer here.

Comment: I have not used Telerik Controls but shouldn't ComboBoxFor render as select and not as input?

Comment: No, I've added HTML that's generated to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/ComboBox?theme=vista).  The ComboBox is being rendered as `<input/>` and a popup `<div/>`

```
<div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default">
  <input type="text" value="Chai" name="ComboBox-input" id="ComboBox-input" class="t-input" autocomplete="off">
  <span class="t-select t-header">
    <span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">select</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

looking at the client side docs, you most likely will need to register a Client-side event located [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/combobox/clientsideevents?theme=vista).

```
   <%= Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
            .Name("ComboBox")
            .ClientEvents(events => events
                .OnChange("onChange")
            )
    %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onChange(e) {
           setConfirmUnload(true);
        }
    </script>
```

it also looks like you should be able to do it with jQuery only from this example:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ComboBox().Name("ComboBox") %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ComboBox').bind('change', function(e) { // your code });
    });
</script>
```

Maybe try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myComboBox').bind("change", function() { setConfirmUnload(true); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Heres a list of events you can attach to:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/combobox/jquery-event-names.aspx

If you want to attach the change event in a more dynamic way with javascript, you would attach to the "valueChange" event and not "change":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ComboBoxId').bind("valueChange", function() { setConfirmUnload(true); }); 
});
```